# Add XCP device and configure variables in XCP/CCP window CANOe by automation

Tags: automated-tests, canoe, com-interface, xcp

I am working on XCP test cases for the first time. I am trying the first step itself to add XCP device and configure few variables by automation. I am aware there exists functions to write and read the variables as normal System Variables once configured in XCP/CCP window.

Is it possible to do add the XCP device and further configure few variables by COM interface or there are already available commands in VT System?

At the moment I have to do add and configure manually and create a Measurement group and activate this group to write and read in tests in CANoe.

Please provide your suggestions! Thank you

I have created test functions using the available VT XCP Commands.

Comment: I went through COM interface document and Vector Support examples.

Comment: Here is the solution. Attaching here incase someone finds useful_

Comment: Dim generalSetup, XCPSetup, ECUs, ECU,  ECU2
Dim App, Measurement, Config

set App = createobject( "canoe.application") 
App.open "C:\PathToMyConfig\myconfig.cfg" 

Set Measurement  = App.Measurement
Set Config    = App.Configuration
Set generalSetup = Config.GeneralSetup
Set XCPSetup     = generalSetup.XCPSetup
Set ECUs         = XCPSetup.ECUs

'Add a new ECU with XCP on CAN
ECU = ECUs.Add("C:\XCPsim.a2l", canoe.eMcTransportLayer.cTlCan) ' or use 0 for cT1Can enum

'ECU = ECUs.AddConfiguration("C:\testimportXcp.xcpcfg")  ' Add xcp configuration

Set App = nothing